The wifi disappers suddenly!
after upgrading to Ubuntu 24.04 my WiFi disappears suddenly after working for a while and I have to restart my machine to get it back.It totally disapears from UI and Settings and lshw shows its unclaimed .Seems like the Wifi Driver breaks. I have Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 hardware.
output of dmesg :
[ 1218.537733] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Unregistering PHC clock: iwlwifi-PTP, with index: 0
[ 1218.632362] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected crf-id 0x3617, cnv-id 0x100530 wfpm id 0x80000000
[ 1218.632380] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: PCI dev 2723/0084, rev=0x340, rfid=0x10a100
[ 1218.639150] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.37
[ 1218.639529] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 1218.639561] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 1218.639656] thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ 1218.764566] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected RF HR B3, rfid=0x10a100
[ 1218.790133] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Hardware error detected. Restarting.
[ 1218.790278] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1218.790282] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[ 1218.790286] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode
[ 1218.790290] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST          
[ 1218.790293] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0020A2B0 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1218.790296] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1218.790298] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004F8B7A | branchlink2
[ 1218.790301] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004EEC2A | interruptlink1
[ 1218.790304] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004EEC2A | interruptlink2
[ 1218.790307] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00014EAE | data1
[ 1218.790310] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | data2
[ 1218.790314] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 1218.790317] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 1218.790319] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0001BD1C | tsf low
[ 1218.790322] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 1218.790325] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 1218.790328] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00021683 | time gp2
[ 1218.790331] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[ 1218.790334] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004D | uCode version major
[ 1218.790337] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xAD46C98B | uCode version minor
[ 1218.790339] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[ 1218.790342] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version
[ 1218.790345] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x8003FC12 | hcmd
[ 1218.790348] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x20020000 | isr0
[ 1218.790351] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | isr1
[ 1218.790353] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[ 1218.790356] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00C0001C | isr3
[ 1218.790359] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 1218.790362] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 1218.790364] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00014EAE | wait_event
[ 1218.790367] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 1218.790370] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00010000 | l2p_duration
[ 1218.790373] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1218.790376] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 1218.790379] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1218.790381] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 1218.790384] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[ 1218.790429] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1218.790432] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[ 1218.790435] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[ 1218.790439] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1218.790441] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80455D2E | umac branchlink2
[ 1218.790444] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac interruptlink1
[ 1218.790447] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac interruptlink2
[ 1218.790449] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000400 | umac data1
[ 1218.790452] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac data2
[ 1218.790455] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 1218.790458] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004D | umac major
[ 1218.790461] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xAD46C98B | umac minor
[ 1218.790463] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0002169F | frame pointer
[ 1218.790466] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0886260 | stack pointer
[ 1218.790469] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 1218.790471] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 1218.790487] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[ 1218.790490] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[ 1218.790504] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00005841 | IML/ROM data1
[ 1218.790519] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[ 1218.790530] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[ 1218.790536] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1218.790543] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1218.790550] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1218.790556] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1218.790563] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1218.790569] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1218.790577] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1218.790584] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1218.790590] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1218.790601] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1218.790643] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1218.790653] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1218.790659] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1218.790666] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1218.790672] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1218.790679] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000000F0 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[ 1218.790711] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x804727d0
[ 1218.790718] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[ 1218.790759] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[ 1218.791367] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW error in SYNC CMD INIT_EXTENDED_CFG_CMD
[ 1218.791377] CPU: 3 PID: 110 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: P        W  O       6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu
[ 1218.791383] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N550JK/N550JK, BIOS N550JK.210 06/12/2019
[ 1218.791388] Workqueue: events request_firmware_work_func
[ 1218.791402] Call Trace:
[ 1218.791407]  <TASK>
[ 1218.791415]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[ 1218.791428]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[ 1218.791437]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[ 1218.791570]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1218.791579]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[ 1218.791620]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[ 1218.791667]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd_pdu+0x6f/0xd0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1218.791820]  iwl_run_unified_mvm_ucode+0x100/0x310 [iwlmvm]
[ 1218.791861]  ? __pfx_iwl_wait_init_complete+0x10/0x10 [iwlmvm]
[ 1218.791896]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1d/0x30
[ 1218.791904]  iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x216/0x420 [iwlmvm]
[ 1218.791940]  iwl_mvm_start_get_nvm+0xaf/0x2c0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1218.791975]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x81d/0xab0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1218.792016]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0xbd/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[ 1218.792058]  iwl_req_fw_callback+0x7b6/0xb40 [iwlwifi]
[ 1218.792091]  request_firmware_work_func+0x56/0xb0
[ 1218.792096]  process_one_work+0x16f/0x350
[ 1218.792106]  worker_thread+0x306/0x440
[ 1218.792110]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[ 1218.792113]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1218.792119]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1218.792122]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1218.792128]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1218.792132]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1218.792140]  </TASK>
[ 1218.792155] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run init config command: -5
[ 1218.792166] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[ 1219.686717] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[ 1219.701635] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 0
[ 1219.702737] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 1219.702818] thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ 1219.852476] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Hardware error detected. Restarting.
[ 1219.852595] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1219.852611] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[ 1219.852614] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode
[ 1219.852618] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST          
[ 1219.852620] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0020A2F0 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1219.852623] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1219.852625] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004F8B7A | branchlink2
[ 1219.852628] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004EEC2A | interruptlink1
[ 1219.852630] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004EEC2A | interruptlink2
[ 1219.852632] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00014EAE | data1
[ 1219.852635] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | data2
[ 1219.852637] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 1219.852640] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 1219.852642] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0001B8C4 | tsf low
[ 1219.852644] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 1219.852646] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 1219.852649] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0002122E | time gp2
[ 1219.852651] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[ 1219.852653] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004D | uCode version major
[ 1219.852656] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xAD46C98B | uCode version minor
[ 1219.852658] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[ 1219.852660] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version
[ 1219.852663] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x8003FC12 | hcmd
[ 1219.852665] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x20020000 | isr0
[ 1219.852666] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | isr1
[ 1219.852668] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[ 1219.852670] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00C0001C | isr3
[ 1219.852672] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 1219.852674] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 1219.852676] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00014EAE | wait_event
[ 1219.852678] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 1219.852680] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 1219.852682] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1219.852684] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 1219.852687] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1219.852689] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 1219.852691] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[ 1219.852735] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1219.852737] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[ 1219.852740] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[ 1219.852742] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1219.852744] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80455D2E | umac branchlink2
[ 1219.852746] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac interruptlink1
[ 1219.852748] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac interruptlink2
[ 1219.852751] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000400 | umac data1
[ 1219.852753] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac data2
[ 1219.852755] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 1219.852756] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004D | umac major
[ 1219.852759] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xAD46C98B | umac minor
[ 1219.852761] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0002124B | frame pointer
[ 1219.852763] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0886260 | stack pointer
[ 1219.852765] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 1219.852767] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 1219.852781] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[ 1219.852783] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[ 1219.852797] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00005850 | IML/ROM data1
[ 1219.852821] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[ 1219.852829] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[ 1219.852834] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1219.852840] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1219.852846] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1219.852852] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1219.852857] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1219.852863] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1219.852868] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1219.852874] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1219.852880] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1219.852888] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1219.852895] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1219.852904] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1219.852910] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1219.852916] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1219.852922] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1219.852927] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000000F0 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[ 1219.852941] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x804727d0
[ 1219.852960] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[ 1219.852982] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW error in SYNC CMD INIT_EXTENDED_CFG_CMD
[ 1219.852988] CPU: 3 PID: 110 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: P        W  O       6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu
[ 1219.852993] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N550JK/N550JK, BIOS N550JK.210 06/12/2019
[ 1219.852997] Workqueue: events request_firmware_work_func
[ 1219.853012] Call Trace:
[ 1219.853017]  <TASK>
[ 1219.853020] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[ 1219.853027]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[ 1219.853042]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[ 1219.853052]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[ 1219.853118]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1219.853125]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[ 1219.853164]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[ 1219.853195]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd_pdu+0x6f/0xd0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1219.853251]  iwl_run_unified_mvm_ucode+0x100/0x310 [iwlmvm]
[ 1219.853277]  ? __pfx_iwl_wait_init_complete+0x10/0x10 [iwlmvm]
[ 1219.853296]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1d/0x30
[ 1219.853302]  iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x216/0x420 [iwlmvm]
[ 1219.853325]  iwl_mvm_start_get_nvm+0xaf/0x2c0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1219.853350]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x81d/0xab0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1219.853374]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0xbd/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[ 1219.853399]  iwl_req_fw_callback+0x7b6/0xb40 [iwlwifi]
[ 1219.853433]  request_firmware_work_func+0x56/0xb0
[ 1219.853438]  process_one_work+0x16f/0x350
[ 1219.853446]  worker_thread+0x306/0x440
[ 1219.853450]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[ 1219.853453]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1219.853456]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1219.853459]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1219.853462]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1219.853464]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1219.853470]  </TASK>
[ 1219.853475] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run init config command: -5
[ 1219.853483] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[ 1220.751712] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[ 1220.765635] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 1
[ 1220.767500] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[ 1220.767654] thermal thermal_zone1: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
[ 1220.921125] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Hardware error detected. Restarting.
[ 1220.921242] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1220.921246] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 6
[ 1220.921250] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode
[ 1220.921253] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000066 | NMI_INTERRUPT_HOST          
[ 1220.921257] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[ 1220.921260] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[ 1220.921263] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004F8B7A | branchlink2
[ 1220.921267] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004EEC2A | interruptlink1
[ 1220.921269] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x004EEC2A | interruptlink2
[ 1220.921272] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00014EAE | data1
[ 1220.921275] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | data2
[ 1220.921278] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[ 1220.921280] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[ 1220.921283] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0001C12D | tsf low
[ 1220.921286] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[ 1220.921288] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[ 1220.921291] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00021A82 | time gp2
[ 1220.921294] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[ 1220.921296] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004D | uCode version major
[ 1220.921299] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xAD46C98B | uCode version minor
[ 1220.921302] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[ 1220.921305] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version
[ 1220.921308] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x8003FC12 | hcmd
[ 1220.921310] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[ 1220.921313] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | isr1
[ 1220.921316] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[ 1220.921320] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00C0001C | isr3
[ 1220.921322] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[ 1220.921325] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[ 1220.921328] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00014EAE | wait_event
[ 1220.921331] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[ 1220.921334] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_duration
[ 1220.921337] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[ 1220.921340] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[ 1220.921343] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[ 1220.921346] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[ 1220.921349] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000020 | flow_handler
[ 1220.921393] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[ 1220.921396] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Transport status: 0x0000004B, valid: 7
[ 1220.921399] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x20000070 | NMI_INTERRUPT_LMAC_FATAL
[ 1220.921403] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[ 1220.921406] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80455D2E | umac branchlink2
[ 1220.921408] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac interruptlink1
[ 1220.921411] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac interruptlink2
[ 1220.921414] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000400 | umac data1
[ 1220.921417] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80472CBA | umac data2
[ 1220.921420] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac data3
[ 1220.921423] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000004D | umac major
[ 1220.921426] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xAD46C98B | umac minor
[ 1220.921428] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00021A9F | frame pointer
[ 1220.921431] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0xC0886260 | stack pointer
[ 1220.921434] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | last host cmd
[ 1220.921437] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[ 1220.921452] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: IML/ROM dump:
[ 1220.921455] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000003 | IML/ROM error/state
[ 1220.921469] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00005830 | IML/ROM data1
[ 1220.921483] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000080 | IML/ROM WFPM_AUTH_KEY_0
[ 1220.921493] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[ 1220.921500] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x60000000 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[ 1220.921506] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[ 1220.921512] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1220.921519] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[ 1220.921525] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[ 1220.921532] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[ 1220.921539] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[ 1220.921545] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[ 1220.921551] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1220.921560] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[ 1220.921568] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[ 1220.921577] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[ 1220.921584] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_PREV_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[ 1220.921602] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_WIFI_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1220.921610] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x00290021 | FSEQ_BT_FSEQ_VERSION
[ 1220.921626] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: 0x000000F0 | FSEQ_CLASS_TP_VERSION
[ 1220.921646] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: UMAC CURRENT PC: 0x804727d0
[ 1220.921653] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: LMAC1 CURRENT PC: 0xd0
[ 1220.921673] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW error in SYNC CMD INIT_EXTENDED_CFG_CMD
[ 1220.921679] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[ 1220.921680] CPU: 3 PID: 110 Comm: kworker/3:2 Tainted: P        W  O       6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu
[ 1220.921684] Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N550JK/N550JK, BIOS N550JK.210 06/12/2019
[ 1220.921687] Workqueue: events request_firmware_work_func
[ 1220.921694] Call Trace:
[ 1220.921697]  <TASK>
[ 1220.921701]  dump_stack_lvl+0x48/0x70
[ 1220.921708]  dump_stack+0x10/0x20
[ 1220.921714]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd_sync+0x1d5/0x370 [iwlwifi]
[ 1220.921767]  ? __pfx_autoremove_wake_function+0x10/0x10
[ 1220.921773]  iwl_trans_txq_send_hcmd+0xb8/0x170 [iwlwifi]
[ 1220.921823]  iwl_trans_send_cmd+0x74/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[ 1220.921900]  iwl_mvm_send_cmd_pdu+0x6f/0xd0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1220.922002]  iwl_run_unified_mvm_ucode+0x100/0x310 [iwlmvm]
[ 1220.922037]  ? __pfx_iwl_wait_init_complete+0x10/0x10 [iwlmvm]
[ 1220.922078]  ? _raw_spin_unlock_bh+0x1d/0x30
[ 1220.922086]  iwl_run_init_mvm_ucode+0x216/0x420 [iwlmvm]
[ 1220.922128]  iwl_mvm_start_get_nvm+0xaf/0x2c0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1220.922171]  iwl_op_mode_mvm_start+0x81d/0xab0 [iwlmvm]
[ 1220.922217]  _iwl_op_mode_start+0xbd/0xf0 [iwlwifi]
[ 1220.922259]  iwl_req_fw_callback+0x7b6/0xb40 [iwlwifi]
[ 1220.922300]  request_firmware_work_func+0x56/0xb0
[ 1220.922305]  process_one_work+0x16f/0x350
[ 1220.922311]  worker_thread+0x306/0x440
[ 1220.922316]  ? __pfx_worker_thread+0x10/0x10
[ 1220.922320]  kthread+0xf2/0x120
[ 1220.922325]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1220.922328]  ret_from_fork+0x47/0x70
[ 1220.922333]  ? __pfx_kthread+0x10/0x10
[ 1220.922336]  ret_from_fork_asm+0x1b/0x30
[ 1220.922342]  </TASK>
[ 1220.922346] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run init config command: -5
[ 1220.922355] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: WRT: Collecting data: ini trigger 13 fired (delay=0ms).
[ 1221.820683] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
[ 1221.835570] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: retry init count 2

partial output of journalctl -e :
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: iwl_trans_wait_txq_empty bad state = 0
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: wlp4s0: failed to remove key (1, ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff) from hardware (-5)
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK wpa_supplicant[1162]: wlp4s0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=c0:3c:04:11:33:95 reason=3 locally_generated=1
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK wpa_supplicant[1162]: BSSID c0:3c:04:11:33:95 ignore list count incremented to 2, ignoring for 10 seconds
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: ------------[ cut here ]------------
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: WARNING: CPU: 3 PID: 4664 at net/mac80211/driver-ops.c:41 drv_stop+0x10f/0x120 [mac80211]
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: Modules linked in: ccm snd_seq_dummy snd_hrtimer rfcomm cmac algif_hash algif_skcipher af_alg qrtr bnep nvidia_uvm(PO) intel_rapl_msr intel_rapl_common x86_pkg_temp_thermal intel_powerclamp nvidia_drm(PO) coretemp snd_hda_codec_hdmi iwlmvm kvm_intel nvidia_modeset(PO) binfmt_misc kvm mac80211 irqbypass libarc4 crct10dif_pclmul polyval_clmulni polyval_generic ghash_clmulni_intel sha256_ssse3 spi_nor snd_hda_codec_realtek uvcvideo sha1_ssse3 snd_hda_codec_generic aesni_intel btusb mtd videobuf2_vmalloc btrtl mfd_aaeon asus_nb_wmi uvc crypto_simd iwlwifi btintel snd_hda_intel cryptd asus_wmi btbcm videobuf2_memops snd_intel_dspcfg snd_seq_midi ledtrig_audio videobuf2_v4l2 rapl btmtk nls_iso8859_1 snd_seq_midi_event spi_intel_platform sparse_keymap snd_intel_sdw_acpi nvidia(PO) mei_hdcp mei_pxp at24 spi_intel snd_hda_codec videodev snd_rawmidi platform_profile intel_cstate i915 bluetooth rtsx_usb_ms cfg80211 snd_hda_core mei_me i2c_i801 videobuf2_common memstick snd_hwdep snd_seq ecdh_generic mxm_wmi mc mei
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel:  i2c_smbus snd_pcm ecc lpc_ich snd_seq_device drm_buddy ttm snd_timer drm_display_helper cec snd rc_core i2c_algo_bit soundcore asus_wireless input_leds joydev mac_hid serio_raw msr parport_pc ppdev lp parport efi_pstore nfnetlink dmi_sysfs ip_tables x_tables autofs4 hid_logitech_hidpp hid_logitech_dj hid_generic usbhid rtsx_usb_sdmmc hid rtsx_usb r8169 ahci xhci_pci crc32_pclmul psmouse realtek libahci xhci_pci_renesas video wmi
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: CPU: 3 PID: 4664 Comm: kworker/3:1 Tainted: P        W  O       6.8.0-31-generic #31-Ubuntu
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: Hardware name: ASUSTeK COMPUTER INC. N550JK/N550JK, BIOS N550JK.210 06/12/2019
May 22 21:44:40 N550JK kernel: Workqueue: events_freezable ieee80211_restart_work [mac80211]

output  of lshw -c network:
 *-network                 
       description: Wireless interface
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
       logical name: wlp4s0
       version: 1a
       serial: 6c:6a:77:a4:0a:ec
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=6.8.0-31-generic firmware=77.ad46c98b.0 cc-a0-77.ucode ip=192.168.2.20 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:18 memory:f7900000-f7903fff


rollbacked to 22.04 for now and it's working perfectly. so something is wrong on 24.04
